# How can I remove the title in a specific node?

Tags: nodes

I am working in Drupal 7.

How can I remove or hidden the title in a specific node (not in the content type of the specific node)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  the [Automatic Nodetitles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) module.

> "auto_nodetitle" is a small and efficient module that allows hiding of the content title field in the form. To prevent empty content title fields one can configure it to generate the title by a given pattern.

If you want to hide the title for the particular node or content type, then you should use [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).

Answer (score 1):

You can write a specific page template for that node, and remove the title tag from that template.